# Oracle SQLLDR - Load Record with Invalid Date, Replace Invalid Date with Null

Tags: oracle, date, sql-loader, ctl, nullif

There are records in my source text file with invalid date values. The invalid date values are inconsistent in format due to manual entry.  I still want to load all of these records, but I want to replace the invalid date value with a null.

Please let me know if/how this is possible via SQLLDR control file commands.  I want to avoid creating any custom functions. Something simple that generally refers to errors/exceptions and that works (unlike the below) is ideal:

DATE "MM/DD/YYYY" NULLIF (FROM_DOS=EXCEPTION)

Thanks!

Comment: Some actual sample data would be useful here to see what we are dealing with.  Edit the original post to include both good and bad date data.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, that won't go in a single pass. I'd suggest you to try a relatively simple approach:

- load the original data "as is"

  - rows with invalid dates won't be loaded, but will end in the **.BAD** file
- then modify the control file:

  - source will now be the .BAD file
  - load NULL into the date column (`FILLER` might help)

---

Alternatively, you might use the source file as an **external table** and write (PL/)SQL against it to load data into the target table. It allows you to actually *code* whatever you want, but - as you said you don't want to create a custom function (which would decide whether the input data is - or is not - a valid DATE value), I presume you'd rather skip that option.

Comment: This is the solution that I decided to use. It addresses any dates with an invalid format (though does not address an invalid value in the appropriate format).                             "CASE WHEN :FROM_DOS NOT LIKE '##/##/####' THEN NULL 
                    ELSE to_date(:FROM_DOS, 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
               END"

Comment: If the target column is of the DATE datatype, this will fail for input data in valid format (##/##/####) but invalid value (such as 67/43/0987), so ...